# My CI build fails because of detect property

Tags: android, android-studio, bitrise, detekt

I just recently updated my arturbosch detekt library in my android app to 1.20.0-RC1 but when I run my build using bitrise CI tool, I get this error message:

[image]

I have checked my detekt config file and "formatting" is spelt correctly. What could be wrong and how do I resolve it.

I my gradle file, I added the autoCorrect Line in this block:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `./gradlew detektGenerateConfig` - detekt will generate proper config file, but keep in mind it will override your current file

Found it in this github [issue](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/issues/5695#issuecomment-1382733573)